# Why can you cast a integer as a void pointer but can't with CString?

Tags: c++, mfc, reinterpret-cast

Just a heads up, I'm referencing from a working code, and I'm trying to implement the same method but with a `CString`.

The below method that works, casting an integer as a void pointer:

```
void **pParam = new void*[2];
pParam[0] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(this);
pParam[1] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(iTrayNumber);
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CInspectionDone::InspectionDoneThread, reinterpret_cast<void*>(pParam), 0, NULL);
```

Whereas if I do the same for CString, I'm getting these errors:

```
CString strTest = _T("Hello");
void **pParam = new void*[2];
pParam[0] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(this);
pParam[1] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(strTest);
```

errors:

```
1>d:\v4\apps\serialcomm.cpp(160) : error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'CString' to 'void *'
1>        Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator, which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast
```

Is it because fundamentally you can't do the same for a `CString`? I tried searching around the internet and it says the function for reinterpret cast is to convert pointer of one data type to another. Unless maybe pointers are just integers and it's being accepted to be casted.

If there are any explanations on this, I'll greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the `Cstring` or the data in the `Cstring`? If the former, you'll need to take the address of the `Cstring`.

Comment: On almost all modern PC-like systems, a pointer basically is an integer, whose value is the address the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: What's more, `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(int)` is always going to be true, `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(CString)` is very likely going to be false.

Comment: Side note: Make sure someone deletes that `void **pParam = new void*[2];` when they're done with it.

Comment: The crux here is `strTest` isn't a pointer, so casting it to a pointer is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: "_The below method that works_": I don't really believe that. The inner casts are either an unnecessary complication or wrong. The only thing that `InspectionDoneThread` is allowed to do with the values is to cast back to the original types. So you could have passed a pointer to a properly-typed `struct` instead. `reinterpret_cast<void*>(pParam)` is also pointless. Conversion from a pointer to `void*` is implicit. What is the reason for all of these casts? `reinterpret_cast` should only very rarely be used. It shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: And take the address as I recommended above will allow the code to compile, but it won't run because `strTest` will go out of scopew and leave you with a pointer to a dead object. This is why the array is being allocated with `new`. Apologies for going tunnel vision on you and giving bad advice. Consider replacing the array with a struct, `new`ing the struct, and assigning to members in the `struct` the data you want to send. Then you only have to provide the address of the struct instance  as a `void *`, an automatic conversion, and most of the rest is still type-checked.

Comment: From the receiving end, the intention is to retrieve the casted pointer as an integer (shown in this two lines >> void **ppParam = reinterpret_cast<void**>(pParam);  / int iTrayNumber = reinterpret_cast<int>(ppParam[0]); So yes, it still gets casted back. I'm aware for the local variable going out of scope, let me try out as you suggested. Much appreciated on the advice!

Comment: Also keep in mind that `CString` has a destructor. Once that has run, any pointer to the object becomes immediately invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` performs a number of specific casts, all of which are needed only in rather special circumstances. You shouldn't need `reinterpret_cast` for what you are doing here.

One of the casts allowed with `reinterpret_cast` is casting one object pointer type to another object pointer type. The effect of this depends on the exact types. This is mostly useful when casting to `char*` or `unsigned char*` to obtain the object representation of an object.

`reinterpret_cast<void*>` is pointless because conversion from any (non-`const`/`volatile`) object pointer type to `void*` is implicit. The cast is not required at all. Even if it is required `static_cast` will do the same and be less risky (since most use of `reinterpret_cast` is likely to end with undefined behavior). This conversion doesn't change the pointer value. The `void*` will point to the same object as the original pointer did. You then need to later cast the `void*` back to the original type with a `static_cast` (no `reinterpret_cast` required either). Casting to other types will almost always end with undefined behavior.

Another conversion `reinterpret_cast` can perform is between object type pointers and integers. This will map the address of the pointer in some implementation-defined way to an integer value (and back). Again the only way this is useful is if you cast the integer value obtained from a pointer back to its original type. Casting a random integer value to a pointer will not likely result in a pointer value that is usable either. All of this is implementation-defined (except for the round-trip pointer->integer->pointer cast leaving the value unchanged).

However there simply is no specific conversion in the list of possible conversions for `reinterpret_cast` that allows casting a class type to a pointer type. So `CString` can't be cast to `void*` in this way. But there wouldn't be any meaningful way to do such a conversion anyway. What would you expect the resulting pointer value to represent?

You should not need any `reintepret_cast` here. A simple structure holding the properly-typed types will do:

```
struct Params {
    CInspectionDone* a;
    int b;
};

void *pParam = new Parames{this, iTrayNumber};

_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CInspectionDone::InspectionDoneThread, pParam, 0, NULL);
```

And then `InspectionDoneThread` can access the parameters with e.g. `static_cast<Params>(arg)->a` and delete the parameters with `delete static_cast<Params>(arg);`.

Or even better use modern C++. Since a decade ago there is `std::thread`, which doesn't require any pointers at all. `InspectionDoneThread` can just be a non-static member function with the integer as argument with appropriate type instead of needing to be a `static` member function with `void*` parameter. And then:

```
auto mythread = std::thread(&CInspectionDone::InspectionDoneThread, this, iTrayNumber);
```

or with a lambda:

```
auto mythread = std::thread([&]{ InspectionDoneThread(iTrayNumber); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and explanation! I spent an hour trying to convert to your methods. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using visual studio 2008 which doesn't accept initialization in this way  >> void *pParam = new Params{this, iTrayNumber}; Therefore, I'm initializing it in two lines, void *pParam = new Params; followed by >> static_cast<Params*>(pParam)->b = iTrayNumber; I would also love to try std::thread but I think version 2008 doesn't support it yet.

Comment: @SinHanJinn It is C++11 syntax. Visual Studio 2008 is very old and C++ is a much better language since C++11. Old Visual Studio is also not really following the C++ standard and uses its own dialect of the language. I think you should consider upgrading your compiler and moving to C++11 at least.

Comment: @SinHanJinn If you set the members individually, then use `Params*` instead of `void*` as the type so that you don't need repeated `static_cast`s.

Comment: Yes I'll be upgrading it soon. Thanks again for your help :)